# All EditTexts are populated with data from one EditText after rotation and backpressed

Tags: java, android, fragment

My app is using stylized EditText fields causing me to use a custom included RelativeLayout with the EditText in every layout needed. The EditTexts all have the same id which seems to be causing this problem:
I have a form with multiple EditTexts all have the same id and are included like so:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/person_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/custom_edit_text" />
```

where I override the included containing RelativeLayout's id so I can later get this editText by calling findViewById(R.id.person_name).findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text). 
Heres the style for the EditText layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_edit_text"
    android:src="@drawable/shadow_left" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_edit_text"
    android:src="@drawable/shadow_right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If the user enters 'a' in one of these EditTexts and then either rotates this fragment or navigates back to it from another screen, all of the included EditTexts display the same 'a' text. I have tried saving all field data in a bundle and loading the savedInstanceState in onCreateView but this only fixes the problem for rotation and not navigating back to this fragment. I could manually have theEditText layouts in each layout instead of using include but that would be a last resort as it would make the xml very messy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing the included relativelayout with a linearlayout allowing me to remove the default EditText id. I then assigned the EditTexts ids programatically calling

```
my_edit_text.setId(R.id.person_name);
```

and adding ids.xml to my res/values with unique ids for each edit text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="person_name" type="id"/>
</resources>
```